# jQuery addClass not working with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple `addClass()` on click function and was wondering why it doesn't work. If I change the `$('#wicked')` to `$('div')`, the click function works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wicked').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('blueBack');
  });
});
```

```css
#wicked {
  background-color: #ABCDEF;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 25px;
}
.blueBack {
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="wicked">Test Button</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
```

Comment: Because `border-style: none;` has higher precendence due to your selector. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Technically this question has nothing to do with jQuery nor JavaScript. Apply your style manually and the result is the same. You should learn basic debugging techniques using the browser's built-in developer tools which would have shown you which of your classes and rules were being applied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually working just fine. The css is simply overwriting your style.

In css `id` has a higher precedence than `class`. So the rule for `id` to have border style of `none` is simply more important than your rule or `solid` border in `class`.

Comment: How do you explain this?: "_If I change the $('#wicked') to $('div'), the click function works fine._"

Comment: @zgood it actually doesn't. This has the same effect in both cases. https://jsfiddle.net/bvxoz4b6/

Comment: ya I agree with you and I think you are correct, I was just trying to account for that statement the OP made - maybe he is just mistaken?

Comment: To anyone else who finds this.  I want to add a class `errorField` to inputs fields with errors, identified by their ID. Using this answer, I solved it by adding `!important` to all the property values within the `errorField` class.